# Google App Engine (GAE) - How to control the depth of the object graph loaded by JPA and exposed through JAX-RS?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jaxb, jax-rs, google-cloud-sql

I am tempted to use the GAE SQL cloud through JPA, but should this go wrong I will fall back to using the datastore with JPA.

I can foresee that if my domain objects are annotated such that Entity A owns Entity B and then Entity B has relationships to Entities C,D and E, then asking JPA for Entity A could load Entities B through E unless lazily loaded.

Because I am planning to use JAX-RS, then when the JAXB marshallers kick in, wouldn't that cause the lazy loading to hydrate the full object graph?

What's the best practice for controlling what's exposed?

I'm currently thinking about writing a DAO layer that explicitly says 'Get me all users but not their children', or 'Get me all users with the login history'.  Will I have this level of control with JPA / JAX-RS, or am I best to write this with SQL queries and JDBC?

Comment: you refer to AppEngine and also SQL and tag it as "gae-datastore". Which Google offering is this ... appengine/datastore (BigTable related datastore) or gae-cloud-sql (RDBMS datastore) ?

Comment: Because I plan to use JPA to perform the persistence, then any underlying implementation/provider (gae-datastore or gae-cloud-sql) will have the same issues.  At present I'm leaning towards the cloud SQL route as I think I will be more comfortable with this.  I ran out of tags I'm allowed to use and I couldn't find the cloud SQL tag (I still can't).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you submit the A entity to JAXB it will inspect its relations, this loading entities B, C and E.

To prevent this, you could annotate the relations with `@XmlTransient`, and they will not be navigated.

Comment: I was hoping to find something more dynamic, so that sometimes I can return the full object graph and other times some of it.  Having this annotations prevents traversal, but it's useful to know.